# Google Maps API v2 - white map tiles on display

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I created test application to learn how use Google maps API v2, but I got only white screen when open the map.Here is my project https://gitlab.com/Ossir/androidgit@gitlab.com:Ossir/android.git
I found a lot of topick here with the simular problem but they didn't solve the problem. I tested app on Google Nexus 7 (android 4.3) and Huawei Honor (android 4.0.2)
Any help?

Comment: Follow this tut for google map http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/showing-current-location-in-google-maps-using-api-v2-with-supportmapfragment/

Comment: your code and the log-cat output are necessary for us to help you.

Comment: code is available on the link, and log-cat from emulator shows no errors, and how to get log-cat from device I don't know

Comment: tutorial didn't solve the problem. Even tutorial source code didn't work. May be my Api key is wrong, but I generate it folowing google dev instraction sha1; package_name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found what was wrong. I need to add

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
```

to androidManifest and everything wors fine